# php session variable only provide old session values

Tags: javascript, session-variables, captcha, php

I was working with a wordpress website, in it i have a page which is using session to store a captcha and retrieve it in another page(contact-page), but the session variable only providing previous captcha value, i couldn't resolve what is the problem here. please someone help me to fix this

**contact page**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage naam
 * Template Name: Contactpage*/
get_header(); ?>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkEmail(email)
{
var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
if (!filter.test(email))
{
return false;
}
else
return true;
}
function checkCaptcha(captcha)
{
var original_captcha = "<?php echo $_SESSION['6_letters_code'] ?>";

alert("original:"+original_captcha+"\n"+"user:"+captcha);
var user_entered_captcha = captcha;
if (original_captcha.localeCompare(user_entered_captcha) == 0)
{
return true;
}
else
return false;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var fname = $('#fname').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var phone = $('#phone').val();
    var mesg = $('#mesg').val();
    var captcha = $('#6_letters_code').val();
    var admineml= 'sarath.sarigama@gmail.com';//'<?php echo get_option( 'admin_email' ); ?>';
var err = 0;
        $('#fnamemsg').html('');
        $('#emailmsg').html('');
        $('#mesgmsg').html('');
        $('#phonemsg').html('');
        $('#captchamsg').html('');


if(fname.search(/\S/) == -1)
{
err = 1;
$('#fnamemsg').html('<font style="color:red">Error ! Enter your name</style>');
}
if(checkEmail(email) == false)
{
err = 1;
$('#emailmsg').html('<font style="color:red">Error ! Enter email address</style>');
}
if(checkCaptcha(captcha) == false)
{
err = 1;
$('#captchamsg').html('<font style="color:red">Error ! Enter the captcha</style>');
}
if(mesg.search(/\S/) == -1)
{
err = 1;
$('#mesgmsg').html('<font style="color:red">Error ! Enter  message</style>');
}
if(phone.search(/\S/) == -1)
{
err = 1;
$('#phonemsg').html('<font style="color:red">Error ! Enter  phone number</style>');
}
    if(err == 1)
    {
    return false;
    }
    else
            jQuery.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/formsub.php",
                                data: {fname: fname, email: email, phone: phone, admineml: admineml, mesg: mesg},
                                success: function(data)
                                {
                                    //alert(data);
                                    if(data=='true')
                                        {
                                        document.getElementById('scs_msg').innerHTML="Submit Successfully";
                                        document.getElementById('scs_msg').style.display="block";
                                        document.getElementById('main').style.display="none";
                                        }
                                    else
                                        {
                                        document.getElementById('scs_msg').innerHTML="Error Please Try again";
                                        }
                                }
                                });
//return true;
});
});
</script>

<section id="container">
    <section class="greyarea">
        <section class="greyareacontainer">
        <section style="clear:both; height:20px;"></section>
            <h1>Contact us</h1>
           <section class="contactBlock">
            <article class="contactBlock_left">
             <?php
            $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'offset'=> 0, 'post_type' => 'address' );
            $myposts = get_posts( $args );
            foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
            ?>  
                <section class="triblock">
                <h1><figure><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/icon1.png" alt="" ></figure>Address</h1>
                <p><?php print_custom_field('address_details'); ?></p>
                </section>
                <section class="triblock">
                <h1><figure><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/mobile.png" alt="" ></figure>
                Phone Number</h1>
                <p><?php print_custom_field('ph_no'); ?></p>
                </section>
                <section class="triblock">
                <h1><figure><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/mail.png" alt="" ></figure>
                Email</h1>
                <p><a href=""><?php print_custom_field('email_add'); ?></a></p>
                </section>
                 <?php  endforeach; ?>  
            </article>
            <article class="contactBlock_middle">
            <figure><?php dynamic_sidebar('g_map'); ?></figure>

            </article>
            <article class="contactBlock_right">

            <div style="display:none;" id="scs_msg"></div>

            <div id="main">
            <div class="errorBlock">
                    <div id="fnamemsg"></div>
                    <div id="emailmsg"></div>
                    <div id="phonemsg"></div>
                    <div id="mesgmsg"></div>
                    <div id="captchamsg"></div>
                    </div>
            <form action="" method="post" novalidate="" id="commentform" class="clform">

                <label>Your Name</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" id="fname">

                <label>Enter email address</label>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email">

                <label>Enter phone number</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone">

                <label>Message</label>
                <textarea cols="" rows="" placeholder="Enter your message" id="mesg"></textarea>


                <img src="http://callagylaw.com/wp-content/themes/callargy/captcha_code_file.php?rand=<?php echo rand(); ?>" id='captchaimg' >

                <label for='message'>Enter the code above here :</label>
                <input id="6_letters_code" name="6_letters_code" type="text">

                <small>Can't read the image? click <a href='javascript: refreshCaptcha();'>here</a> to refresh</small>


                <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">
                </form>
                <script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>
                function refreshCaptcha()
                    {
                        var img = document.images['captchaimg'];
                        img.src = img.src.substring(0,img.src.lastIndexOf("?"))+"?rand="+Math.random()*1000;
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
            </article>
           </section>



        </section>
    </section>



</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**captcha generating code**

```
<?php 
/*
*
* this code is based on captcha code by Simon Jarvis 
* http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-captcha.php
*
* This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or 
* modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License 
* as published by the Free Software Foundation
*
* This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, 
* but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of 
* MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the 
* GNU General Public License for more details: 
* http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
*/

session_start();
//Settings: You can customize the captcha here
$image_width = 120;
$image_height = 40;
$characters_on_image = 6;
$font = './monofont.ttf';

//The characters that can be used in the CAPTCHA code.
//avoid confusing characters (l 1 and i for example)
$possible_letters = '23456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz';
$random_dots = 0;
$random_lines = 20;
$captcha_text_color="0x142864";
$captcha_noice_color = "0x142864";

$code = '';


$i = 0;
while ($i < $characters_on_image) { 
$code .= substr($possible_letters, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible_letters)-1), 1);
$i++;
}


$font_size = $image_height * 0.75;
$image = @imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);


/* setting the background, text and noise colours here */
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

$arr_text_color = hexrgb($captcha_text_color);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, $arr_text_color['red'], 
        $arr_text_color['green'], $arr_text_color['blue']);

$arr_noice_color = hexrgb($captcha_noice_color);
$image_noise_color = imagecolorallocate($image, $arr_noice_color['red'], 
        $arr_noice_color['green'], $arr_noice_color['blue']);


/* generating the dots randomly in background */
for( $i=0; $i<$random_dots; $i++ ) {
imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$image_width),
 mt_rand(0,$image_height), 2, 3, $image_noise_color);
}


/* generating lines randomly in background of image */
for( $i=0; $i<$random_lines; $i++ ) {
imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$image_width), mt_rand(0,$image_height),
 mt_rand(0,$image_width), mt_rand(0,$image_height), $image_noise_color);
}


/* create a text box and add 6 letters code in it */
$textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $font, $code); 
$x = ($image_width - $textbox[4])/2;
$y = ($image_height - $textbox[5])/2;
imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $font , $code);


/* Show captcha image in the page html page */
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');// defining the image type to be shown in browser widow
imagejpeg($image);//showing the image
imagedestroy($image);//destroying the image instance
$_SESSION['6_letters_code'] = $code;

function hexrgb ($hexstr)
{
  $int = hexdec($hexstr);

  return array("red" => 0xFF & ($int >> 0x10),
               "green" => 0xFF & ($int >> 0x8),
               "blue" => 0xFF & $int);
}
?>
```

Comment: Can't just destroy/unset session to force it to make a new one when it's ran on the new page?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not Miss understood your question You First need to display captcha in form like:

```
<img src="showCaptcha.php" alt="captcha"  />
<br/>
<label >Verify You are not a BOT</label>
<input type="text" name="captcha" placeholder="Enter the text shown above"  required/>
```

Then When the user submits the form you can use get captcha value.

In Simple words you first need to run captcha script and then you can retrive the captcha value stored in session.

Hopefully it helps if not please comment and I will be happy to help

Comment: how do i run the captcha first?

Comment: you need to display captcha in form first like above then it will automatically set session value

Comment: Then whats the session value being printed ?

Comment: are you including the php file again ?